# Android Countdown Timmer does not stop

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I am new to Android I need some help.
I am using countdown timmer to update a text view up to some date. Its working fine but the timmer does not stop at 0:0:0:0 it keeps going on as this 0:0:0:-12.

I want the text view text to change to Start at 0:0:0:0.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setLenient(false);


        String endTime = "22.05.2019, 23:48:00";

        Date endDate;
        try {
            endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
            milliseconds = endDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        diff = milliseconds - startTime;


        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                startTime = startTime - 1;

                Long serverUptimeSeconds =
                        (millisUntilFinished - startTime) / 1000;

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time left :" + serverUptimeSeconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String daysLeft = String.format("%2d", serverUptimeSeconds / 86400);

                String hoursLeft = String.format("%2d", (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600);

                String minutesLeft = String.format("%2d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);

                String secondsLeft = String.format("%2d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
                countdownTimerText.setText(daysLeft + ":" + hoursLeft + ":" + minutesLeft + ":" + secondsLeft);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countdownTimerText.setText("Start");

            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountdownTimers API takes `millisInTheFuture` and an `interval`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long,%20long)

much easier to do something like

`new CountdownTimer(TimeUnit.Seconds.toMillis(30), TimeUnit.Seconds.toMillis(1))`

//^ this will countdown 30 seconds in interval of 1 second

---

You do basically this:

```
String endTime = "22.05.2019, 23:48:00"; 
milliseconds = endDate.getTime(); // 1558565280
new CountdownTimer(milliseconds, 1000)
```

which will countdown from a very big number :-) (1558565280 millis == 432.93 hours)

---

Perhaps you meant to do:

`countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(diff, 1000)`

Comment: Can you share any example beacuse i am unable to understand you.

Comment: on this line `countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {` change `milliseconds` to `diff`